# Code Browser / method overview in normal matlab GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

Matlabs "App Designer" shows a "Code Browser" window in the GUI, which lists all properties and methods in the class. I'm currently writing a "normal" class (not in App Designer) and would like to have this nice overview of my properties and methods as well.

Unfortunately I don't see any option to enable a similar type of window in the normal matlab environment (I would expect the option to be under Home->Layout). Searching the internet for "matlab code browser" or "matlab methods overview gui" and similar terms does not return any relevant results either.

My question is: Is it possible to get an overview of my methods/properties in the normal matlab gui, as is possible in App Designer?

I'm using matlab R2020a.

Example of what I want:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you can get something similar using the "Current Folder" window:

Home -> Layout -> Show: Current Folder

Click on the file that contains the class and the properties and methods will be displayed in the "Details" window. Double clicking a method/property will navigate the editor to where it is defined.